# Interpolate matrices for different times in Matlab

Tags: matlab, grid, interpolation

I have computed variables stored in a matrix for a specific time vector.
Now I want to interpolate between those whole matrices for a new time vector to get the matrices for the desired new time vector.

I've came up with the following solution but it seems clunky and computational demanding:

```
clear all;

a(:,:,1) = [1 1 1;2 2 2;3 3 3]; % Matrix 1
a(:,:,2) = [4 4 4;6 6 6;8 8 8]; % Matrix 2

t1 = [1 2]; % Old time vector

t2 = [1 1.5 2]; % New time vector

% Interpolation for each matrix element
for r = 1:1:size(a,2)
for c = 1:1:size(a,1)
tab(:) = a(r,c,:);
tabInterp(r,c,:) = interp1(t1,tab(:),t2);
end
end
```

The result is and should be:

```
[2.5000    2.5000    2.5000
    4.0000    4.0000    4.0000
    5.5000    5.5000    5.5000]
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the linear interpolation manually, and all at once...

```
m = ( t2 - t1(1) ) / ( t1(2) - t1(1) );  
% Linear interpolation using the standard 'y = m*x + c' linear structure
tabInterp = reshape(m,1,1,[]) .* (a(:,:,2)-a(:,:,1)) + a(:,:,1);
```

This will work for any size `t2`, as long as `t1` has 2 elements.

If you have a `t1` with more than 2 elements, you can create the scaling vector `m` using `interp1`. This is relatively efficient because you're only using `interp1` for your time vector, not the matrix:

```
m = interp1( t1, (t1-min(t1))/(max(t1)-min(t1)), t2, 'linear', 'extrap' );
```

---

This uses implicit expansion with the `.*` operation, which requires R2016b or newer. If you have an older MATLAB version then use `bsxfun` for the same functionality.

Comment: @jodag I've updated my answer and resolved this issue, can now do it in one hit with multiple valued `t1`.

Comment: Thanks for that great input. It works flawless. I've also tried to use interp3. What do you think is faster?

clear all;
a(:,:,1) = [1 1 1;2 2 2;3 3 3]; % Matrix 1
a(:,:,2) = [4 4 4;6 6 6;8 8 8]; % Matrix 2
t1 = [1 2]; % Old time vector
t2 = [1 1.5 2]; % New time vector
% Interpolation for each matrix element
[X, Y, Z] = meshgrid(1:size(a,1), 1:size(a,2), t1);
[X2, Y2, Z2] = meshgrid(1:size(a,1), 1:size(a,2), t2);
tabInterp = interp3(X,Y,Z,a,X2,Y2,Z2);

Comment: Why don't you `timeit` and see? If you want to ask a related but different performance question, it's easier to do so as a new question rather than in the comments :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't really see a problem with a loop based approach, but if you're looking for a loopless method you can do the following.

```
[rows, cols, ~] = size(a);
aReshape = reshape(a, rows*cols, []).';
tabInterp = reshape(interp1(t1, aReshape, t2).', rows, cols, []);
```

Looking at the source code for `interp1` it appears a `for` loop is being used anyway so I doubt this will result in any performance gain.